# How to use page numbering with a prefix - like 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 and so on

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, ieeetran

I am writing a journal in IEEE format and have trouble controlling the page numbering. I use this default template I found

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\section{page 1}
\newpage
\section{page 2}

\end{document}
```

The page numbering is just the standard, 1 2 3 4... but I want my group number (number 10) to be in front of the actual page number. Such that page one has numbering 10.1, page to has numbering 10.2, page 3 has 10.3 and so on.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Maybe simply adding this to your preamble: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{10.\arabicpage}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to add packages that can change the layout of the page, you can simply do (after `\begin{document}` for example):

```
\renewcommand\thepage{10.\arabic{page}}
```

...but I did not test if this creates problems for cross-references later (I do not know the internal of the IEEE class).

Comment: Ops, same-time as @Bernard.

Comment: Yes! This is just what I wanted.

Comment: It looks like the position of the page number is in the IEEEtran template. If you do not want to change that template itself, you can move the page number with the fancyhdr package, see my new answer. But: the bottom margin of the template seems to bee very small. Therefore I increased it to 1 inch for which I had to use the geometry package as well.

Comment: @Rmano: No worry…

Comment: @Rmano One last thing. Is it possible to place the page number in the bottom right corner of the page, instead of the top right corner?

Comment: @Carl It is quite uncommon to (re)direct a question - which in fact was and still is also a new question and should have been posted as a new question - directly to a specific person.

Comment: @C.Peters It is not at all uncommon to ask the answerer elaborate on their answer (at least not at the other SE's I'm on like math and electrical engineering). By the way I tried to apply the code in your second answer (now that is uncommon, to post two answers on the same question) but it still had bold font and the page number on the first page wasn't correct.

Comment: I do not know what you are doing exactly, but the font in my code is not bold, it is just the normal font of the document (it becomes bold when I add bfseries). You can change the font as you wish. The place of the page number of the first page has to be adjusted manually, because the first page normally uses pagestyle{plain} and not {fancy}. Anyway, you asked two different questions: one about the appearance of the page number,  and one about its place.

Comment: @C.Peters By placing pagestyle{fancy} a different place in the code I got it to work on the first page. However, it is still bold font. Is there such a thing as normalfont command?

Comment: This should restore the normalize: \normalsize{10.\arabic{page}}, but I cannot test it with your letter size, because it is not explicitly defined in the preamble. When I say \small instead of \normalsize, the page number still is a little bit bigger than in your MWE, when I say \tiny it becomes too small.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{\flushright 10.\arabic{page}}% when you add \bfseries before the 10 you will see how the letter looks when it is bold. If you want an other letter type you can put it before the 10.
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand\bottom=15pt%
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set the page style to fancy
\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\section{page 1}
\newpage
\section{page 2}

\end{document}
```